# Wordpress with Composer and different plugins for dev/live.

Tags: plugins, wp-dependencies, composer

I'm using a Bedrock-like setup where I handle Wordpress core & plugins with Composer. I have my usual plugins in my composer.json within the "require" block, and some dev related plugins in "require-dev".

On dev/staging I do `composer install` and on the live site I do `composer install --no-dev`. Thats fine and all, but when migrating the database from staging to live, Wordpress complains that these missing plugins aren't on the live site (which of course they aren't thats the point.)

I'm just wondering how people generally solve this, or should I just ignore this message?

Comment: Maybe this project helps you - http://wecodemore.github.io/wpstarter

Comment: I'm not sure how this helps. Could you point me to something specific or elaborate perhaps?

Comment: The database entry list all plugins from the dev, missed the dev plugins and the check is not a point from composer. Maybe you can change this database entry, reformat before staging. The entry is only a serialized string. The idea was, that the linked project have a answer to your question in his documentation, maybe.